# Apache POI - Writing to Excel template without overwriting existing cell formatting

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am using Apache POI to write data to an Excel template. The template only contains headers on the first row, but I also applied specific styles to the entire column (e.g. Accounting and Percentage).

It would be nice to use these formats when I write data to the new cells. But if I use the `createRow` and `createCell` methods, the cell format is overwritten and I get General for all the cells. If I try to use `getRow` and `getCell` instead, I run into NullPointerExceptions retrieving the blank cell.

Is there a way to use the pre-existing cell formatting saved in the template? Or am I stuck setting the data format myself through the API?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have applied specific styles to an entire column, then you can retrieve that `CellStyle` with [`Sheet`'s `getColumnStyle` method](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#getColumnStyle%28int%29), passing it the 0-based column index.  It retrieves a normal `CellStyle` object that can be used anywhere else `CellStyle`s are accepted, such as in [`Cell`'s `setCellStyle` method](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#setCellStyle%28org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle%29).

For avoiding the `NullPointerException`, both `getRow` and `getCell` may return `null` if the row or cell doesn't exist, respectively.  You will need to call `createRow` and/or `createCell` to create the `Cell`, on which you can always call `setCellStyle`.

Comment: That worked perfectly! I just had to add `cell.setCellStyle(sheet.getColumnStyle(index))`. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

`cell.setCellStyle(sheet.getColumnStyle(index)`  works well.